# Saving sqlite database in cached directory instead of documents

Tags: objective-c, ios, sqlite, ios5

Until now my database was saved in the documents directory of application. Now Apple refuse to do it anymore and I need to change the directory.

Does anyone know how to save a database in cached directory, or even direct me to a tutorial/example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The caches directory will be the last entry returned from `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains`:

```
NSString *cachesPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *dbPath = [cachesPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mydatabase.db"];
```

Comment: I have the same problem. So I have a such question: Is that cash directory will still "alive" while user makes update to my application? Simply I save all user settings in DB and I don't want it to be erased with new version of an app.

Comment: Ask your question as a proper SO question, so others can benefit from the answers.